# Pytest doesn't set attribute to mock object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

Here is a test case code:

```
def test_interactive_session_set_language(monkeypatch):
    """Test user possibility to select language."""

    events = [':ru-en', EOFError]

    mock_input = mock.Mock(side_effect=events)

    mock_set_language = mock.Mock()

    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', mock_input)
    monkeypatch.setattr('pylingvo.interactive.pylingvo.client.set_language',
                        mock_set_language)

    with pytest.raises(SystemExit):

        pylingvo.interactive.start_session()

    assert mock_set_language.call_count == 1
```

Here is a module code:

```
import pylingvo.client
import sys
import re


def start_session():
    """Start interactive session."""

    while True:

        try:

            line = input('> ')

        except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):

            sys.exit()

        else:

            command = dispatch(line)


COMMAND_MATCH_PATTERNS = [
    ('^:[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}$', pylingvo.client.set_language),
    ('^.*$', Exception),
]


COMMAND_MATCH_TABLE = [(re.compile(regex), command)
                       for regex, command in COMMAND_MATCH_PATTERNS]


def dispatch(command_name):
    """Convert interactive input to callable object."""

    for pattern, command in COMMAND_MATCH_TABLE:

        if pattern.match(command_name):

            return command
```

This test case failed with this message:

```
E       assert 0 == 1
E        +  where 0 = <Mock id='139806765631632'>.call_count
```

As we can see mock object doesn't called due test run.  So my question
is how to set mock attribute properly then this test case can pass?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're patching the wrong target. Try this:

```
monkeypatch.setattr('pylingvo.client.set_language', mock_set_language)
```

Comment: This change doesn't help.